# How to generate 3 non repeated random numbers from a range?

Tags: php

Using PHP, how can I select 3 numbers from a numbers range, that don't repeat theirselves?

For example from a range 1 - 100, an answer may be 5, 32, 12, but not 5, 5, 93

Thank you

Comment: have you tried something yourself?

Comment: google is you're friend. Just look up how to it once then do it x times until you get 3 numbers.

Comment: Easiest way is to use a loop to check last generated number and ignore new one if match the last one :)

Comment: Range, shuffle slice.

Comment: @AbraCadaver cheers, you've just made me think of cake.

Comment: @Pashiamas it does seem homeworky, but you have 10 gold badges, so I assume you know not to do that. Then again, I would have also assumed someone with as many famous question as yourself would have provided us with some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create array of numbers from 1 to 100:

```
$numbers = range(1, 100);
```

Shuffle all numbers:

```
shuffle($numbers);
```

Retrieve only 3 of them:

```
$randomNumbers = array_slice($numbers, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$numbers = [];
$min = 1;
$max = 3;

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $rnd = rand($min, $max);
    while(in_array($rnd, $numbers)){ // while generated random number is already in the numbers array
        $rnd = rand($min, $max); // generate a new random number
    } // loop ends when newly generated random number is not in the array already
    array_push($numbers, $rnd); // push the new random number into the array
}
```

It will generate 3 different numbers between 1 and 3, and save them into the `$numbers` array.